# ContourPlot has weird Jagged line

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make a series of contour plots, but pretty much everything I try (and I've tried many different equations) ends up with at least one jagged line of the form seen in the image.  I don't think these jagged lines are particularly meaningful (but I could be wrong), so it'd be nice if they were gone.  I've tried using Exclusions, in a variety of formats (p>q, p<=q,True), but none of them seemed to work (they did get rid of some of the useful data which isn't helpful). Changing the number of PlotPoints doesn't particularly help, and it makes the code take forever to run.  Here is the code that made the pasted image.

```
y = (p - q) + pg - m*h
ClearAll[m]

eq5 = p == q (1 + ρ 2 (1 + 3 y^2)/(1 - y^2)^3)
mset = 0;
ρset = .1;

table5 = Evaluate[
   Table[Evaluate@
     eq5, {pg, {0, 0}}, {m, {mset, 
      mset}}, {ρ, {ρset, ρset}}]];

plotpoints = 150;

fulltable = Flatten[Union[{table5, q == 0, p == q}]];

ContourPlot[Evaluate[fulltable], {p, -10, 10}, {q, -100, 100}, 
 PlotPoints -> plotpoints, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> True]
```

[image: ContourPlot with weird jagged lines]

Comment: I tried to format your code but when I run it in version 10.1 I get a blank output plot.  Could you check it please?

Comment: I get a blank output too (10.0.2)!

Comment: I double checked. It works perfectly, but in 9.0.  Try eliminating the Evaluate[] in the last command?

ContourPlot[fulltable, {p, -10, 10}, {q, -100, 100}, 
 PlotPoints -> plotpoints, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> True]

Comment: Okay, I've cleaned it up to its essentials.  Try:

ContourPlot[
 p == q (1 + (2 (1 + 3 (p - q)^2) (.1))/(1 - (p - q)^2)^3), {p, -10, 
  10}, {q, -100, 100}, PlotPoints -> plotpoints, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> True]

Comment: maybe just let the code with big `PlotPoints` run for several hours? `ContourPlot[
 p == q (1 + (2 (1 + 3 (p - q)^2) (.1))/(1 - (p - q)^2)^3), {p, -3, 
  3}, {q, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 600, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> True]` gives smooth result in my testing. You can also try playing with `MaxRecursion` a bit.

Comment: I think your problem is a bad range for `q`.  The solutions are fairly close to the line `p == q`, and you can see from the above example that `q` doesn't go beyond about 11, even though the range is set much higher.  Using the range `{q, -10, +10}` fixes the problem.  Someone want to write this up as an answer?

Comment: You probably want `fulltable = Union[Flatten[{table5, q == 0, p == q}]]` since the way you have it, `Union` does nothing but sort.

Answer (score 8):

`ContourPlot` has trouble with discontinuous functions and the setting `Exclusions -> True` does not get the job done here.  Let's help it out.  When solving symbolic equations, it helps to have exact coefficients, so I'll use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) on the equations in `fulltable` to compute the exclusions in `excl`.

```
plotpoints = 50;
fulltable = Union[Flatten[{table5, q == 0, p == q}]];

excl = Cases[
   FactorList /@ (Rationalize@fulltable /. 
      Equal -> Subtract), {poly_ /; ! NumericQ[poly], _?Negative} :> 
    poly == 0, Infinity];
(*
  {p == q, p == (1 + (0.2 (1 + 3 (p - q)^2))/(1 - (p - q)^2)^3) q, q == 0}
  {-1 + p - q == 0, 1 + p - q == 0}
*)

ContourPlot[Evaluate[fulltable], {p, -10, 10}, {q, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> plotpoints, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> excl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's a view of the discontinuities, rotated by `Pi/4`.

```
Plot3D[p - (1 + (0.2` (1 + 3 (p - q)^2))/(1 - (p - q)^2)^3) q /. {p ->
     x + y, q -> -x + y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 51, 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
 MeshShading -> {Directive[Opacity[0.5], Yellow], 
   Directive[Opacity[0.5], LightBlue]}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 Exclusions -> {1 - (p - q)^2 == 0 /. {p -> x + y, q -> -x + y}}, 
 PlotRange -> 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Responses to comments:

(1)  One may get rid of the gaps introduced by the `Exclusions` option by plotting where the numerator (of the fraction resulting from [`Together`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Together.html)):

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Thread[Numerator@Together[fulltable /. Equal -> Subtract] == 0],
 {p, -10, 10}, {q, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> plotpoints]
```

(2) Forgive me, but I'm not sure I understand the distinction between limiting range of a parameter in a parametric plot and limiting the plot range.  Below is a parametric plot of the wiggly contour.  Is that what you want?  (Note the errors are unimportant, because that's what happens when the parametric solution heads towards infinity.)

```
fn = First@Numerator@Together@Union[Flatten[table5] /. Equal -> Subtract]
sol = NDSolve[{{p'[t], q'[t]} == (Cross[D[fn, {{p, q}}]] /. {p -> p[t], q -> q[t]}),
     {p[0], q[0]} == {0, 0}}, {p, q}, {t, -4, 4}]
(*
  -1. p + 3. p^3 - 3. p^5 + p^7 + 1.2 q - 8.4 p^2 q + 15. p^4 q - 
   7. p^6 q + 7.8 p q^2 - 30. p^3 q^2 + 21. p^5 q^2 - 2.4 q^3 + 
   30. p^2 q^3 - 35. p^4 q^3 - 15. p q^4 + 35. p^3 q^4 + 3. q^5 - 
   21. p^2 q^5 + 7. p q^6 - 1. q^7
*)
```

> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == -3.9211. >>
>   NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 3.921095435807773`. >>

```
{{p->InterpolatingFunction[{{-3.9211,3.9211}},<>],
  q->InterpolatingFunction[{{-3.9211,3.9211}},<>]}}

ParametricPlot[{p[t], q[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, -3.4, 3.4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to have resolved the bulk of my difficulties, even if I'm not totally sure why it did so.  I do have 2 related questions, though.  First, and I know I'm being picky here (i.e., this isn't terribly important), can I smooth the graphs out again so those 'gaps' are filled up in a sensible manner.

Second, is there an easy way to exclude the portion of the graph that goes between zero and infinity (the portions that bend over backwards).  They aren't meaningful and only confuse everything.

Thanks!

Comment: @Necarion (1) In fact, this is what I normally do: `ContourPlot[Evaluate@Thread[Numerator@Together[fulltable /. Equal -> Subtract] == 0], {p, -10, 10}, {q, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> plotpoints]`.  Somehow I focused on the exclusions.  (2) Do you mean something like this?: `ContourPlot[.., {p, -2,  2}, {q, -2, 2}]`  Or are you asking about the 3D plot?

Comment: (1) I don't understand what's going on in your first point.  What is it doing?
(2) I'm asking about the 2D Plot, but not simply restricting the plotting range. The plot is obviously not single-valued, but there are portions of the double-value that take the lines to infinity (For example, coming _from_ infinity on q = p + const in the positive direction, and going _to_ infinity on q = p - const in the negative direction). If it were a parametric plot, I could restrict the range of the parameter, but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: (1) It sets the numerator equal to zero (after putting the terms together into a simple fraction).  (2) See update

Answer (score 3):

```
ContourPlot[
 p == q (1 + (2 (1 + 3 (p - q)^2) (.1))/(1 - (p - q)^2)^3), {p, -10, 
  10}, {q, -100, 100}, PlotPoints -> 150, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> True]
```

[image]

It seems to be the division in your expression that's giving you problems.  Multiplying by `(1 - (p - q)^2)^3` on both sides gives us:

```
ContourPlot[
 p (1 - (p - q)^2)^3 == 
  q ((1 - (p - q)^2)^3 + (2 (1 + 3 (p - q)^2) (.1))), {p, -10, 
  10}, {q, -100, 100}, PlotPoints -> 150, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> True]
```

[image]

The remaining bit of fuzzyness comes from the fact that your range for `q` is too large: it goes from `-100` to `100` when the actual range in the plot is more like `-11` to `+11`.  Setting the range to something more reasonable gives us:

```
ContourPlot[
 p (1 - (p - q)^2)^3 == 
  q ((1 - (p - q)^2)^3 + (2 (1 + 3 (p - q)^2) (.1))), {p, -10, 
  10}, {q, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 150, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> True]
```

[image]

The reason the plot was stretched to the point where it looked bad was that you set `PlotRange -> All`, which zooms in to cover only the plotted points, even if they cover only a fraction of the range the plot was computed for.  For a `ContourPlot` where you have already explicitly set the range this option is unnecessary, and can conceal range problems like this.  In fact, the only option you need is `MaxRecursion -> 3`, since none of the features of the graph are small enough to be missed at the default `PlotPoints` setting.

```
ContourPlot[
 p (1 - (p - q)^2)^3 == 
  q ((1 - (p - q)^2)^3 + (2 (1 + 3 (p - q)^2) (.1))), {p, -10, 
  10}, {q, -10, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

---

Note that this equation becomes greatly simplified when you rotate your coordinate system 45 degrees with the transformation

$$
u = \frac{p-q}{\sqrt{2}} \\
v = \frac{p+q}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Applying this to your original equation:

```
Simplify[Rationalize[
   p == q (1 + (2 (1 + 
            3 (p - q)^2) (.1))/(1 - (p - q)^2)^3)] /. {p -> (u + v)/
     Sqrt[2], q -> (v - u)/Sqrt[2]}]
```

$$
\frac{80 u^7-120 u^5+54 u^3+6 u^2 v-11 u+v}{2 u^2-1}=0
$$

This is trivially solved for $v$:

```
Simplify[Solve[%, v]]
```

$$
v=\frac{-80 u^7+120 u^5-54 u^3+11 u}{6 u^2+1}
$$

And plotted:

```
Plot[v /. %, {u, -1.1, +1.1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Note that you can use `ParametricPlot` to display the solution in the original `p`, `q` coordinates.